# How to make a jump ruler

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, androiddesignsupport

I don't know "jump ruler" is right words to talk about this

Now, I want to make a thing like below image

**Description about it**: When I move finger on it, It make my screen jump to content contains a character like on a ruler

[image]

how I can make this ?.

Answer (score 1):

I can't add a comment, so let be it. As I understood, you need an "alphabetical scroll for a recyclerView".

There are:

1. a [myinnos library](https://github.com/myinnos/AlphabetIndex-Fast-Scroll-RecyclerView)
2. first [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43966539/how-can-i-make-a-list-with-alphabetical-scrolling)
3. second [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38507825/android-alphabetical-fast-scrollview-in-recyclerview-with-collapsing-toolbar)
4. third [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815425/recyclerview-with-alphabet-index)
5. [random example from github](https://github.com/code-computerlove/FastScrollRecyclerView)

And many more... Just google it.